Angular : How to send a trigger to the parent from a directive
I am working with a directive created a while ago by a colleague who no longer works here. I use it to open dynamic overlays triggered by events.
For example I can do :
<button [myDirective]="getTheComponentToOpenAsOverlay()"></button>

When I use the button, it opens an overlay based on a component and some configuration options :
public getTheComponentToOpenAsOverlay(): DynamicOverlayConfig<TheComponent> {
    return {
        component: TheComponent,
        data: {
            ...
        },
        hostRef: this.appContainer,
        removeOnScroll: true,
        removeOnOutsideClick: true
    };
}

In the "TheComponent" I set up html/css and any function I need.
But now, I need to update my parent component (in which I open the overlay) after executing some functions. I'd gladly use the @Output from Angular, but I don't see how to use it in this case : I call the component using a directive, not with its selector.
I guess I could add a service to broadcast calls from the child to the parent, but I'm not sure this is a good way of doing things.
Here's the directive code, I guess it'll help :
import { ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Directive, 
EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, Output, SimpleChanges, Type, 
ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { DynamicOverlayReadyEvent } from './dynamic-overlay.interface';

export interface DynamicOverlayConfig<T> {
    component: Type<T>;
    hostRef?: ViewContainerRef;
    data?: { [key in keyof T]?: any };
    removeOnScroll?: boolean;
    removeOnOutsideClick?: boolean;
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]',
})
export class SyDynamicOverlayDirective<T> implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {

    @Input('syDynamicOverlay') config: SyDynamicOverlayConfig<T>;
    @Output('onSyDynamicOverlayReady') onSyDynamicOverlayReady: EventEmitter<DynamicOverlayReadyEvent> = new EventEmitter();
    componentFactory: ComponentFactory<T>;
    dynamicComponentRef: ComponentRef<T>;
    isComponentCreated = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    listeners: Map<string, EventListener> = new Map();

    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) createRemoveDynamicOverlayComponent(event: Event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (this.hostRef && this.componentFactory) {
            if (!this.isComponentCreated.getValue()) {
                this.createComponent();
            } else {
                this.removeComponent();
            }
        }
    }

    constructor(
        private hostRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    ) {
        this.isComponentCreated.subscribe(isComponentCreated => {
            if (this.dynamicComponentRef) {
                if (isComponentCreated) {
                    if (this.config.removeOnScroll) {
                        this.removeOnScroll();
                    }
                    if (this.config.removeOnOutsideClick) {
                        this.removeOnOutsideClick();
                    }
                } else {
                    this.removeListeners();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.config?.currentValue) {
            if (changes.config.currentValue.component) {
                this.componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(changes.config.currentValue.component);
            }
            if (changes.config.currentValue.hostRef) {
                this.hostRef = changes.config.currentValue.hostRef;
            }
        }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.onSyDynamicOverlayReady.emit({overlayApi: this.generateDynamicOverlayApi()});
    }

    removeOnOutsideClick() {
        const outsideClickListener = event => {
            event.stopPropagation();
            if (this.dynamicComponentRef) {
                const clickedInside = this.dynamicComponentRef?.location?.nativeElement?.contains(event.target);
                if (!clickedInside) {
                    this.removeComponent();
                }
            }
        };
        this.listeners.set('click', outsideClickListener);
        window.addEventListener('click', outsideClickListener);
    }

    removeOnScroll() {
        const scrollListener = () => {
            this.removeComponent();
        };
        this.listeners.set('scroll', scrollListener);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);
    }

    removeComponent() {
        // Find the component
        const componentIndex = this.hostRef.indexOf(this.dynamicComponentRef?.hostView);
        // Remove component from both view and array
        if (componentIndex !== -1) {
            this.hostRef.remove(componentIndex);
        }
        this.isComponentCreated.next(false);
        this.removeListeners();
    }

    createComponent() {
        this.hostRef.clear();
        this.dynamicComponentRef = this.hostRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
        Object.keys(this.config.data).forEach(key => {
            this.dynamicComponentRef.instance[key] = this.config.data[key];
        });
        this.isComponentCreated.next(true);
    }

    removeListeners() {
        this.listeners.forEach((listener, eventType) => {
            window.removeEventListener(eventType, listener);
        });
        this.listeners = new Map();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.removeListeners();
    }

    generateDynamicOverlayApi() {
        return {
            close: this.removeComponent.bind(this)
        };
    }
}

Is it even possible to do it with my current code ?
I tried adding an @Ouput on the DynamicOverlayDirective but I have no idea how to call it from my child component, I'm not event sure that it is possible.

But why @Output is not viable for you? I can see that you already have one output there onSyDynamicOverlayReady

Well I can't use it ? Or if I can I don't understand how. If I try to add @Ouput on my button (first code example) it doesn't work. I can't bind a function from the "MyComponent" to the Ouput inside the directive

In your example, it would be just <button [myDirective]="getTheComponentToOpenAsOverlay()" (onSyDynamicOverlayReady)="doSomethingWithIt($event)"></button>

Alright but, how to trigger it from the component invoked in the directive ? I don't see how I access it from there

Do you need to emit on this output from within button component? If so, you can actually inject intsance of directive into your component and emit manually on this input, but soulds like antipattern.

No, from within the component opened by the directive. The directive makes a component to appear on screen, and that's the one which should trigger the output

Ah ok, therfore you have to provide an interface for the spawned component to communicate with directive. The same is happening when you are using MatDialog where dialog component receives DialogRef. In your case it would be something like MyDirectiveRef that would be injected into created component

I'll try to do that and update the post if I encounter any trouble, thanks !

If i remember correctly, in your createComponent, factory#createComponent accepts instance of injector as second argument where you can include provider for the directive using this instance.

Instead of trying to pass the event, you could set a callback fn inside the data attribute.
public getTheComponentToOpenAsOverlay(): DynamicOverlayConfig<TheComponent> {
    return {
        component: TheComponent,
        data: {
            somethingInsideTheComponentHappen: (x: any) => this.actionInHostComponent(x)
        },

and inside your overlay component you could then call data.somethingInsideTheComponentHappen(x).
